# How to have a variable size ad unit in Google DFP under one creative?

Tags: ads, google-dfp, advertisement-server

I have a 3rd party publisher tag (Glam Media) that is a variable size (300x250 and 300x600) and is filled based on what they can fill. How do I get my DFP tags on my site to resize properly based on the ad size being served in the creative? (DFP is forcing me to either have a 300x250 creative or a 300x600 creative, but I cant have a dynamic one that adjusts based on ad size)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/82276), DFP will automatically resize larger ad units so that they don't show whitespace with smaller creatives.  So the solutions should be to simply create a 300x600 ad unit, which DFP should automatically size appropriately when the content is loaded.  I have only done this with multiple different defined-size creatives within an ad unit though, not with a creative that could have a variable size.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the Glam Media tag as an expandable ad. You'll need to switch to sync mode to do this though (if you don't want to get creative with Javascript).

In this case you either serve a 300x250 or a 1x1 tag in DFP and Glam will take as much space as they need.